# Bash comparison floating number

Tags: bash

I have an array:

```
pole_registru=("3" "8" "3.2" "6" "1" "3" "1.3" "3.3" "5.8" "12" "0" "3")
```

I need find elements in the array which are lower than 1 (including number with floating points) and count them (number of lower elements save to variable *A*).

I try:

```
for i in "${pole_registru[@]}"
do
  Hodnota="Value of actual: $i"
  compare=`echo "$i" | bc`
  echo --$compare--
  if [ $i < 1 ]; then (( A+=1 )); else (( A=A )); fi
  echo "$Value ($x) ($A)"
  sleep 1
done
```

Issue into console:

```
./kontrolaNul.sh: řádek 33: 1: Folder or file does not.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bc` directly to compare the numbers, like this

```
pole_registru=("3" "8" "3.2" "6" "1" "3" "1.3" "3.3" "5.8" "12" "0" "3")
for i in "${pole_registru[@]}"
do
  Hodnota="Value of actual: $i"
  if (( $(bc <<< "$i<1") )) ; then (( A+=1 )); else (( A=A )); fi
  echo "$Value ($i) ($A)"
  sleep 1
done
```

The double parentheses construct is used to evaluate the string output of `bc` as a numerical value. (I also changed `$x` to `$i` in the `echo` line)

That gives:

```
$ . t.sh 
 (3) (1)
 (8) (1)
 (3.2) (1)
 (6) (1)
 (1) (1)
 (3) (1)
 (1.3) (1)
 (3.3) (1)
 (5.8) (1)
 (12) (1)
 (0) (2)
 (3) (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:

```
for i in "${pole_registru[@]}"
do
  Hodnota="Value of actual: $i"
  compare=`echo "$i" | bc`
  echo --$compare--
  if [ `echo "$i < 1" | bc` -eq 1 ]; then (( A+=1 )); else (( A=A )); fi
  echo "$Value ($x) ($A)"
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Explanation of the `if` line: The actual comparison is executed in `bc` and the resulting __1__ after the `-eq` may rather be regarded as a TRUE in boolean in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your *immediate* problem is that you're using `<` in your expression, which is the input file redirection operator - it's complaining because you have no file called `1` to get input from.

If you change that to `-lt`, it will fix that problem.

However, I don't think the `bash` numerics cater for floating point so you'll probably have more trouble after that.

One way to get around that limitation is to use an external tool that *does* do floating point, use it to subtract one from your test number, then use the `bash` regular expression matching to detect a negative number:

```
if [[ $(echo $i - 1 | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc) =~ - ]] ; ...
```

The `bc` program is used to calculate `x - 1` for your given `x`, don't worry about the `BC_LINE_LENGTH` setting, that's just to prevent line wrapping within `bc`).

Then, if the result starts with a `-` character, the result was obviously less than zero (because `x` was less than one).